# Function to count second word characters in cell

Tags: excel

I need to find the character count of last/second word in Excel cell.
Example: `John Smith` - I need a function, that would calculate the length of the word `Smith`. In that case, that would be `5`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go : `=IFERROR(LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","☃",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))));LEN(A1))`

My response is inspired from the solution of **m4573r** in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/680769/i-need-to-find-the-last-space-in-a-xls-cell)

Comment: @Toomas, did the answer help you ?

Answer (score 0):

You mention it's the second/last word in a cell you're trying to count. If it's always a two word string, so the second word is always also the last word, you can use a very simple formula of

```
=LEN(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,256))
```

This will count how many characters there are after the first space.

Comment: Nor El Malki's answer is more complete though. Don't forget to mark an answer as correct if it helps you.